# Protractor, setting value of dropdown list

Tags: testing, protractor

Hi I have a sign up form that uses ngRepeat to create a month form field for the date of birth. 
In my Protractor test I'd like to be able to set/select the value of month. As you would with the sendKeys function to populate a input field.

Stephen

Comment: Can you try setting your date by sending keys to the dropdown?

Comment: I tried this 

`this.createFakeChild = function() {
  this.childsName.sendKeys('childsName');
  this.childDayOfBirth.sendKeys('01');
  this.childMonthOfBirth.sendKeys('Jan');
  this.childYearOfBirth.sendKeys('2016');
 };`

But I get 'cannot focus element'.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 01

```
Select based on drop-down values attribute details
```

```
public selectOptionByValue(element: ElementArrayFinder,valueToSelect: string) : void{
        let clickedIndex: number;
        element.first().$$('option').filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getAttribute("value").then(function(value) {
                if (value === valueToSelect) {
                    elem.click();
                    console.log('Yes ! Found option is:' + value);
                }
                return value === valueToSelect;
            });
        }).then(function (bool) {

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```

Solution 02

```
Select based on drop-down visible text details
```

```
public selectOptionByText(element: ElementArrayFinder,optionToSelect: string) : void{
        let clickedIndex: number;
        element.first().$$('option').filter(function(elem, index) {
            return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
                    if (text === optionToSelect) {
                        elem.click();
                        console.log('Yes ! Found option is:' + text);
                    }
                return text === optionToSelect;
            });
        }).then(function (bool) {

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Ooops ! Error... '+err.message);
        });
    }
```